# Created Assets are not persisted between Fabric server reboots

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I followed the [Hyperledger-composer tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html)
 to install all components and everything went well. 
I was able to create assets and participants and can interact with them via REST API Services. 
However, after I rebooted the Fabric network all the assets and participants were gone and I have to recreate them.

Did I miss some settings in docker-composer.yaml or others for data persistence?

I did follow the instruction on page 16 about the "a Note on Data Persistence" to mount a dir into the container.

Answer (score 0):

If you shutdown all Fabric nodes then you will lose all data. AFAIK Fabric does not yet have tools to replay the transaction logs from disk on restart of the entire Fabric. You should use Fabric support channels to confirm this however.

Comment: Thx Dan and will follow up on this as you suggested.

Comment: you should look into using CouchDB.